# Import packageDefinition '.' InterfaceDefinition when defining xtext grammar

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, xtext

I am trying to create a simple grammar using xText. The grammar should define language for Java Interfaces (only) and currently I am struggling with import declarations. I want to be able to reference other interfaces form other packages that I have defined using their FQNs. Here is how my grammar look like:

```
DomainModel:
    elements=AbstractElement;

AbstractElement:
    'package' packageDeclaration=PackageDeclaration 
    'import'? importDeclarations+=ImportDeclaration*
    typeDeclaration=TypeDeclaration;

PackageDeclaration:
    name=QualifiedName ';';

ImportDeclaration:
    importedNamespace=[ReferncedType|QualifiedName] ('.*')? ';';

ReferncedType:
    PackageDeclaration |InterfaceDeclaration; //need to combine both?? separated by '.'

TypeDeclaration:
    'interface' interfaceDeclaration=InterfaceDeclaration;

TypeList:
    Type ( ',' type+=Type)*;

Type:
    typeDefinition=[ReferncedType|ValidID];

InterfaceDeclaration:
    name=ValidID ('extends' superType=TypeList)? body=InterfaceBody;

InterfaceBody:
    '{' (declarations+=InterfaceBodyDeclaration)+ '}';

InterfaceBodyDeclaration:
    interfaceMemberDelcaration+=InterfaceMemberDeclaration ';';

InterfaceMemberDeclaration:
    InterfaceMethodDeclaration;
InterfaceMethodDeclaration:
    (Type | 'void') name+=ValidID '(' (formalParameters+=FormalParameters)* ')' ('throws'
    ....)?;
```

I have defined both files:

```
package org.first.sample;

interface Demo {
   void getA();
}
```

....

```
package org.second.sample;

import org.first.sample.Demo; // this line says that the reference to org.first.sample.Demo is invalid, but I am able to reference org.first.sample

interface AnotherDemo {
   Demo getDemo();
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Nope, the Demo class is compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @laune is right. Xtext supports this out of the box. As long as the referred types in the model have feature called 'name', the fully qualified name of the type is built out-of-the box. What I noticed that is wrong in my Xtext grammar definition is that Package should contain Interface, so that when a fully qualified name is formed xtext is constucting it by combining the 'name' of the Interface with the 'name' of the package (or its parent).
@Fabien your answer is correct in case the xtext grammar rules doesn't contain 'name' features. It is a custom way of building fqns if for example we are using this:

```
Package:
 'package' name=ID ';' imports=Import ';' interface=Interface ';'
;

Interface:
 qualifier=Qualifier !id=ID (instead of name=ID)
;
```

Then we should construct explicitly the fqn because the built-in support looks for 'name' features only.

So in my case the correct way to use this is:

```
 Package:
 'package' name=ID; imports=Import typeDefinition=TypeDefinition;

Import:
 'import' importedNamespace=[TypeDefinition|QualifiedName] ';'
;

TypeDefinition:
  InterfaceDefinition | EnumDefinition ...
;

InterfaceDefinition:
 qualifier=Qualifier !name=ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read the grammar:

```
ImportDeclaration:
    importedNamespace=[ReferncedType|QualifiedName] ('.*')? ';';

ReferncedType:
    PackageDeclaration |InterfaceDeclaration; //need to combine both?? separated by '.'

PackageDeclaration:
    name=QualifiedName ';';
```

So `import` can be followed by a (PackageDeclaration=QualifiedName **followed by a** `;` and then, back to rule ImportDeclaration, another `;` must follow.

Also, I don't understand why ReferncedType can also expand to an InterfaceDeclaration, which is the entire thing?

**Later**

So, perhaps the "import" should be defined as

```
AbstractElement:
    'package' packageDeclaration=PackageDeclaration 
    importDeclarations+=ImportDeclaration*
    ...

ImportDeclaration
   'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedName ('.*')? ';';
```

It doesn't permit static imports, and something must be done to keep track of .* if it occurs.

Comment: Well, I am not really sure what the ReferencedType rule should contain. I just need to be able to import types as it is in Java ( import com.somepackage . TypeName) or (com.sompackage.*)

Comment: See my "Later" addition.

Comment: Thanks but this won't throw compilation error in case the imported package is not a valid one. It will compile with any valid qualified name. I need to refer to only existing types.

Comment: Should this work in any way as a Java compiler does? If so, the qualified name is used to access a class file or, if all participate in a compilation, the qualified name must ultimately refer to an (elsewhere) declared interface. But the interface will not appear literally and complete in the import.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a custom QualifiedNameProvider to override name exported by your interfaces.
Something like this should make the import reference ok : (import org.first.sample.Demo;)

```
public class CustomQualifiedNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {
    @Override
    public QualifiedName getFullyQualifiedName(EObject obj) {
        if (obj instanceof InterfaceDeclaration && obj.eContainer().eContainer() instanceof AbstractElement) {
            QualifiedName packageQualifiedName = getFullyQualifiedName(((AbstractElement)obj.eContainer().eContainer()).getPackageDeclaration());
            return packageQualifiedName.append(((InterfaceDeclaration) obj).getName());
        }
        return super.getFullyQualifiedName(obj);
    }
}
```

Also, you can press Ctrl + Shift + F3 to see what name have your exported objects.